# animation of two object using csv file

Tags: animation, mesh, file-format, fcurves, csv

i have two different mesh in blender and i want both of them move independently using different f-curve at same time and using different csv files but i am not able to do that. Is there any way to do that?

Comment: Csv? do you mean svg (imported)? Try to add a meaningful screenshot (use the editor add image tool) to explain what you did and is not working...

Comment: @m.ardito assume it's comma separated values.

Comment: @batFINGER I know what a csv is, I thought about a typo. But how he is assuming he can "move" a mesh by its f-curve with a csv..? is it possible, how? I think at least it could need a python script maybe?

Comment: Definitely would require Python, but it might be possible

Comment: @m.ardito pretty sure you would.  On q my guess is Rajneesh want's to [read one csv file](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/71458/how-to-read-a-csv-file-and-use-the-values-as-x-and-y-points-in-blender/71466#71466) with frame location etc etc to animate (create fcurve) for one object, ditto for another.

Comment: thanks for replying. csv is comma separated files. i have two mesh and two csv files and my csv files contain x, y and z locations for mesh and i want to animate both mesh at same time using python which is i am not able to do.